# $browser.notifyWhenNoOutstandingRequests doesn't take controller function into account

Tags: javascript, angularjs, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests, phantomjs

We are testing angular webapp with phantomjs.

Controller code looks like this:

```js
angular.module('module' ['dependency']).
    controller('controller',function ($scope, Model) {
        // blah-blah-blah
        Model.list() // calls $http.get
            .then(); // yadda-yadda-yadda
    });
```

Backend is in java, so in order to test the whole app, we're using Selenium Webdriver and PhantomJS.
I use this snippet to check if angular has finished processing it's directives (got it from [protractor](https://github.com/angular/protractor) source code).

```js
var app = angular.element(document.querySelector('#ng-app'));
var $browser = app.injector().get('$browser');
$browser.notifyWhenNoOutstandingRequests(function () {
    // callback
});
```

It works fine - in most of cases it really can detect angular processing requests.

The problem is that sometimes my callback seems to fire even before controller gets executed. In all cases where i've noticed that behavior, it's a route change.
I've tried inserting `alert('');` into different parts of controller to find that out.

So, the question is - how can i execute my waiting snippet **only after** controller function was executed?

Comment: Same here. May be related to https://github.com/angular/protractor/issues/255 And note that `notifyWhenNoOutstandingRequests` is a private, undocumented API function.

Comment: Could you say a little more about the snippet from the protractor source?  I'm getting a response that says injector() is undefined when using the exact code in Selenium's javascript executor.

Comment: @emery, you must use selector that matches your app's root element or any child element of it. angular.element(null) would return an empty array instead of throwing an exception. array doesn't have injector field, hence the error.

Comment: Thanks ilj.  In my case,  "html[class*=ng-app]" seems to work, whereas "#ng-app" does not.

Answer (score 2):

[Per the GitHub discussion](https://github.com/angular/protractor/issues/255), the issue you mention is specific to PhantomJS.  Other environments seem fine.

Caveat:  I don't use Phantom, and this talk is 1 year old (as of Dec 2014) — so it's possible that this is no longer an issue.

Comment: glad I could still be of help